# What happens if we define wrong flag for -mfpu?

Tags: gcc, simd

For example, if I have a chip `-mcpu=cortex-a7` , I should define `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4` , not `-mfpu=neon` . However, I'm wondering what will happen if I define -`mfpu=neon` on Cortex-A7? Will it just ignore the flag and don't do the SIMD, or what will it do with the wrong flag like that?

Comment: A relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269946/cortex-a9-neon-vs-vfp-usage-confusion

Comment: It will either complain or use the wrong instructions.

Answer (score 2):

It will use an older set of NEON instructions (`-mfpu=neon` is for selecting the NEON instructions that are available on the Cortex-A8 core). For example, it will not include the VFMA instructions.

Note that from [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html#arm) (still in development) you will be able to just use `-mfpu=auto` or leave out the `-mfpu` entirely and have the compiler pick the optimal FPU setting for the `-mcpu` option you selected

Answer (score 0):

If you do this compiler won't use VFPv4 instructions and potentially generate suboptimal code.