# Which[neon/vfp/vfp3] should I specify for the mfpu when evaluate and compare float performance in ARM processor?

Tags: performance, arm

I want to evaluate some different ARM Processor float performance. I use the `lmbench` and [`pi_css5`](http://myownlittleworld.com/miscellaneous/computers/piprogram.html), I confuse in the float test.

From `cat /proc/cpuinfo`(below), I guess there're 3 types of float features: neon,vfp,vfpv3? From this [question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097034/arm-cortex-a8-whats-the-difference-between-vfp-and-neon), it seems it's depend to the compiler.
Still I don't know which I should to specify in compille flag(`-mfpu=neon/vfp/vfpv3`), or I should compile the program with each of that, or just do not specify the `-mfpu`?

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo               
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 532.00
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x2
CPU part    : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 4
```

Comment: As it applies to performance, the *soft* versus *hard* will have a big impact; this  is generally baked into the compiler and *libc* and can not be changed by an `-mfpu` option.  See [Debian hard float wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort).  This has nothing to do with the specific op-codes, but has to do with the way interfaces between routines are used.  This can also affect performance.

Answer (score 8):

It might be even a little bit more complicated then you anticipated. [GCC arm options page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) doesn't explain fpu versions, however [ARM's manual for their compiler](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CIHCJIFE.html) does. You should also notice that [Linux doesn't provide whole story about fpu features](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c#L956), only telling about `vfp`, `vfpv3`, `vfpv3d16`, or `vfpv4`.

Back to your question, you should select the greatest common factor among them, compile your code towards it and compare the results. On the other hand if a cpu has vfpv4 and other has vfpv3 which one would you think is better?

If your question is as simple as selecting between `neon`, `vfp` or `vfpv3`. Select `neon` [(source)](http://doc.ironwoodlabs.com/arm-arm-none-eabi/html/getting-started/sec-armfloat.html).

```
-mfpu=neon selects VFPv3 with NEON coprocessor extensions.
```

From the *gcc* manual,

> If the selected floating-point hardware includes the NEON extension
>        (e.g. `-mfpu=neon`), note that floating-point operations will
>        not be used by GCC's auto-vectorization pass unless
>        `-funsafe-math-optimizations' is also specified.  This is because
>        NEON hardware does not fully implement the IEEE 754 standard for
>        floating-point arithmetic (in particular denormal values are
>        treated as zero), so the use of NEON instructions may lead to a
>        loss of precision.

See for instance, [Subnormal IEEE-754 floating point numbers support on ios...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346521/subnormal-ieee-754-floating-point-numbers-support-on-ios-arm-devices-iphone-4) for more on this topic.

Comment: I have two ARM devices and two toolchains provided by manufacturer. One CFLAGS variable says `-mfpu=vfpv3-d16` and another says `-mfpu=vfpv3`. Which is the greatest common factor between these two? Does `vfpv3` floating-point instructions with 32 double-precision registers always "include" `vfpv3-d16` floating-point instructions with 16 double-precision registers?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried each one of them, and it seems using the `-mfpu=neon` and to specify the `-march=armv7-a` and  `-mfloat-abi=softfp`  is the proper configuration.

Besides, a referrence([ARM Cortex-A8 vs. Intel Atom](http://www.ee.unlv.edu/~meiyang/ecg700/readings/ARM%20Cortex-A8%20vs.%20Intel%20Atom.pdf)) is of great useful for ARM BenchMark.
Another helpful article is about [ARM Cortex-A Processors and gcc command lines](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/933-arm-cortex-a-processors-and-gcc-command-lines/), this clears the SIMD coprocessor configuration.

Comment: The `-mfloat-abi=softfp` is a function of the compiler and not the CPU.