# VFP and NEON use

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, neon

I have recently started working on arm cortex-A15, As per my understanding VFP works on sequential while NEON on parallel. Can anyone tell me which one gives better optimization? My algo needs sequential flow.  because AFAIK mixing VFP and NEON will give poor performance. My development is in `opencv` `c++`. Can anyone explain me how could I use VFP?

Comment: This refers https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762516/2836621